# How to pass authorization value from cookie file and custom headers to getjson?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, getjson

I need to do a getJSON request, but how do i pass authorization and custom headers? The authorization value is asp.net sessionID(ASP.NET_SessionId:drfgjsdfkgdff4534) saved in cookie.txt and custom header is user agent(MozillaXYZ/1.0).

**Could any one show me how i can send sessionID value and custom header via getjson request ?**

in php  we send sessionId from cookie and custom header useragent like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0"
```

**But how to send these 3 header items using getjson ?**

```
 <script>
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.someremotesite.com/page3.php&callback=?', function(data){
    //$('#output').html(data.contents);

 var siteContents = data.contents;    

//writes to textarea 
document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents ;

</script>
```

edited: I used ajax instead of getjson but after using beforeSend the ajax stopped pulling data!could any one tell me what is wrong?

```
<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://anyorigin.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

$.ajax({
        url: 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.someremotesite.com/page3.php&callback=?',
        type: 'GET',

        dataType: "json",
        success: displayAll
        beforeSend: setHeader
    });



function displayAll(data){
   // alert(data.contents);

document.myform2.outputtext2.value = data.contents ;
}



function setHeader(xhr) {


        xhr.setRequestHeader('ASP.NET_SessionId', 'rtretretertret43545435454');

      }


</script>
</head>

<body>
<br>



<form id="myform2" name="myform2" action="./3.php?Id=&title=test" method="post">
<td><textarea rows="14" cols="15" name="outputtext2" style="width: 99%;"></textarea></td>

</form>


</html>
```

Comment: Read the whole docs for jQuery $.ajax function which you will need to use instead of $.getJSON to use the additional options.

Comment: Thanks for reply . If i use $ajax can still use cross domain anyorgin.com service ?

Comment: Probably. You'd have to try it. I say that because `$.getJSON` just calls `$.ajax` inside.

Comment: thanks i tried it ajax can use anyorgin.com service but now how i can send value of sessionIdv from cookies.txt via ajax request? is there any example of how to send custom header and cookie value using $.ajax ?

Comment: Headers are described in the docs. Cookies are set via standard Javascript cookie mechanism and tied to the URL used.

Comment: ee meador I edited my first post could you tell me what is wrong with the way i send header ? after placing beforeSend the ajax stoped pulling data from remote site! Nothing is wrong with ajax only problem is with sending header !

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set the header:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://something.com/ajax',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: displayAll,
    headers : {
        'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'rtretretertret43545435454'
    }
});
```

Don't forget to add the comma after 'displayAll' as its missing in your question.

Comment: thanks lee. But for somereason i dont get the protected page! it seems the sessionId is not sent to remote site via anayorgion.com service or i am missing something else. In php send the whole cookie.txt was bypassing the login but not here!